# Color picker with redactor

Tags: jquery, redactor, jscolor

I would like to use a color picker with redactor where I will be able to select colors as in :-

http://jscolor.com/try.php

I just tried to do it by calling jscolor function from the redactor custom plugin file but the color picker is not showing.

The error I get is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'showPicker' of undefined"

Is it possible to show this color picker as "redactor" plugin

Editor used here is

http://redactorjs.com/

My plugin code

```
if (!RedactorPlugins) var RedactorPlugins = {};

  RedactorPlugins.background = function()
  {
 return {
    init: function()
    {

        var bg = this.button.add('background color', 'Background Color');

        this.button.addCallback(bg, this.background.formatBg);

        jscolor.init()


    },
    formatBg: function()
    {
        document.getElementsByClassName("re-background").color.showPicker();
    }
};
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName("re-background").color` isn't an object which is why you're getting that error. Look at the color picker in the source code for redactor and you can see how they did it and change it to use your own.